# if input value equals specific text, display

Tags: if-statement, input, equals

I'm learning jQuery slowly but surely, so please excuse my ignorance. I did a lot of googling that resulted in the Frankenstein example below.

In this example, if the user enters "Kasey" or "KASEY" or "Kasey" into the input, I would like div#pete to have display:block.

Thanks in advance!

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
  
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fname").keyup(function () {
        $("#pete").css("display", this.value == "Kasey,KASEY,Kasey" ? "block" : "none");
    });
});

</script>


</head>
<body>

<p>Name: <input type="text" id="fname"></p>
<p id="pete" style="display:none;" >Pete</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fname").keyup(function () {
        if(this.value == "Kasey" || this.value=="KASEY" || this.value=="Kasey"){
            $('#pete').css("display", "block");
        }else{
            $('#pete').css("display", "none");
        }
    });
});

</script>


</head>
<body>

<p>Name: <input type="text" id="fname"></p>
<p id="pete" style="display:none;" >Pete</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. You were very close, you could have amended your code to read like this: `(this.value == "Kasey" || this.value == "KASEY) ? "block" : "none"`

The example below makes use of `indexOf`. I've created an array of possible values, then using `indexOf()` to check if the typed value exists in the array.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var acceptedValues = ["Kasey", "KASEY"];
    $("#fname").keyup(function () {
        $("#pete").css("display", (acceptedValues.indexOf(this.value) != -1) ? "block" : "none");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all

This code work perfect

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#country").keyup(function () {
        $("#question").css("display", this.value == "france" || this.value == "France"  ? "block" : "none");
  $("#reponse").css("display", this.value == "france" ? "block" : "none");
    });
});
```